# How to get data from Parse.com in a list and apply it in listview?

Tags: c#, parse-platform, xamarin

I'm very new to Parse.com and can't seem to get fetching of data working.
I tried an async method which did a foreach but that never seemed to work so then I did a try with a `ParseQuery` but that didn't work either.
For example:

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseObject.GetQuery("Horse");
string name = query.Get<string>("Name");
Debug.WriteLine("Horse: " + name);
```

Ideally I would like to get **all** records from the model `Horse` and then loop over it to fill up a listview. I now have a hardcoded sample but since I don't even get all records from the table in a list I have no clue how to continue.

```
var listView = new ListView
        {
            RowHeight = 40
        };
        listView.ItemsSource = new string[]
            {
            //This should be filled up with the field 'Name' from the model 'Horse' dynamically..
            "Buy pears",
            "Buy oranges",
            "Buy mangos",
            "Buy apples",
            "Buy bananas"
            };
        Content = new StackLayout
        {
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
            Children = { listView }
        };
```

Could anybody give me a helping hand here please? I followed the guide from https://parse.com/docs/dotnet_guide#objects-retrieving but those options do not seem to work.

**Update:**
So far I can fetch all the data thanks to the answer from har07.
Now I get an error when I want to fill up the ListView:

```
public async void getHorsesFromDb()
    {
        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseObject.GetQuery("Horse");
        IEnumerable<ParseObject> horses = await query.FindAsync();

        var listView = new ListView();
        List<string> horseList = null;

        foreach (ParseObject horse in horses)
        {
            string name = horse.Get<string>("Name");
            horseList.Add(name);
            Debug.WriteLine("Horse: " + name);
        }

        listView.ItemsSource = horseList;

        // Using ItemTapped
        listView.ItemTapped += async (sender, e) => {
            await DisplayAlert("Tapped", e.Item + " row was tapped", "OK");
            Debug.WriteLine("Tapped: " + e.Item);
            ((ListView)sender).SelectedItem = null; // de-select the row
        };
    }
```

Error on my screen:

```
The current stack frame was not found in a loaded module. Source cannot be shown for this location.
>   0x21 in System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Mono_UnhandledException_internal    C#
```

Comment: When using hard-coded values for `ItemsSource` did your apps also crash? Which line exactly triggering that error?

Comment: It also crashes when adding hard-coded values for the ItemsSource. It seems to crash when settings the ItemsSource (listView.ItemsSource = horseList;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The link you're following shows how to get single row data (`ParseObject`) by passing the particular `objectId` (which value is `xWMyZ4YEGZ` in that example) to the query.

On the other hand, to get multiple rows from a table follow [Queries](https://parse.com/docs/dotnet_guide#queries) section of the same. Getting all rows should even be simpler (no need to write any LINQ up to this point) :

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseObject.GetQuery("Horse");
IEnumerable<ParseObject> horses = await query.FindAsync();
foreach (ParseObject horse in horses)
{
    string name = horse.Get<string>("Name");
    Debug.WriteLine("Horse: " + name);
}
```

Comment: Hmm that actually makes sense, thanks! Alright so then I'm wondering.. How could I now fill up a ListView in the foreach from this data? I'll update my question with the code that I have, since it crashes.